# What is the correct way to handle exceptions and catch errors in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function written in javascript to check if the login details are correct.
This is the function:-

```
 login:(phone,key)=>{
        const regId=md5(phone);
        localStorage.setItem('regId',regId);
        return fetch(
            `${serverAddress}/api/account/login?phone=${phone}&key=${key}&regId=${regId}&appType=M`,
            {
                method:'POST',
                accept:'application/json',
            }
        ).then((res)=>{
            if(res.ok){
                return res.json();
            }else{
                throw new Error('Fetch Error');
            }
        });
    },
```

This function is written within Client file which I am accessing in the route as this:-

```
class Login extends Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        redirect:false,
        email: "",
        password: ""

      }
    }


    checker(){
            var phone=8724055040;
            var pass=9435363285;
            Client.login(phone,pass).then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    redirect:true           
                });
            })   
    }          

    render(){
        if(this.state.redirect){
            return(
                <div>HEY</div>
            )
        }
        else{
            return(
                <form>
                      Phone: <input type="text" name="pno"></input><br></br>
                      Password: <input type="text" name="pass"></input><br></br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.checker}></input>
                 </form>                
            );
        }
    }
}
export default Login
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to re-render the component in case the entered credentials are correct using setState. But if they are wrong I also want to get the error as in the login function above. What is happening right now is I get this link in my url bar and nothing happens:-

```
http://localhost:3000/login?pno=8724055040&pass=9435363285
```

How to fix this and make it what I want it to become?

Comment: For sure youll want to use event.preventDefault() in your checker function. This doesn’t answer the question but should stop the url bar from changing. Checker will have to take an event as an parameter. On mobile otherwise I’d have an answer for you.

Comment: sure ...then give me an answer when you reach your pc ...that will help

Answer (score 0):

Try like below to catch the exception handling and use the below link
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function() {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```